# How can I learn the Power App Studio?

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

Please recommend a good or official resource for learning Power App Studio.

Is there an official documentation?  Is there a recommended training guide?  Is there an official YouTube channel and video focused on this task?

Comment: Check below learning resources and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check below learning resources for Power Platform (Power Apps, Power Automate, etc.):

1. [Microsoft Power Platform: Learning Resources](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-powerapps-learning-resources/) - Includes blog/forum/Training labs/workshops/YouTube channel links.
2. [Power Platform resources](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/resources)
3. [Microsoft Power Platform documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/)
4. [Microsoft Power Platform developer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/developer/)
5. [Microsoft Power Platform admin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/)
6. [Microsoft Power Apps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/)